# Add values of identical rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, jsonp

I have a MYSQL table containing facebook advertising data.

I am using the Facebook Ads API to get all adset for a specific account.
In the result I have some adsets with identical names, because of adset being deleted for a new one, for a difference time period.

F.x.

```
NAME                     SPEND    
Gistrup   MSN Standard - 11
Storvorde MSN Standard - 12
Vejgaard  MSN Standard - 13
Aalborg   MSN Standard - 14
Gistrup   MSN Standard - 15
Storvorde MSN Standard - 16
Vejgaard  MSN Standard - 17
Aalborg   MSN Standard - 18
```

The number is the amount spend on the adset.

Then I have this script to select the data and output is as JSON

```
 $fb_sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id_campaign_shortname = '". $_GET["lpage"] ."' AND date_from = '". $date_from ."' AND date_to = '". $date_to ."'";

        $fb_sth = $db->dbh->query($fb_sql);
        $fb_result = $fb_sth->fetchAll();

        $merged_data = array_merge($fb_result);

        $jsonArray = array();

        if(count($merged_data) > 0) {

            $total = 0;

            foreach($merged_data as $elm) {

                array_push($jsonArray, array(
                    "campaign" => array(
                        "campaignName" => $elm["campaign_name"],
                        "campaignAdsetName" => $elm["adset_name"],
                        "campaignReach" => $elm["reach"],
                        "campaignSpend" => $elm["amount_spent"],
                        "campaignCPC" => $elm["cpc"],
                        "campaignClicks" => $elm["clicks"],
                        "campaignId" => $elm["id_name"],
                        )
                    )
                );

                $total += $elm["reach"];

            }


            $jsonCampaignDataArray = array("campaignData" => $jsonArray);
            $jsonTotalReach = array("totalReach" => $total);

            $finalArray = array_merge($jsonCampaignDataArray, $jsonTotalReach);

            $json = json_encode($finalArray);

            echo $_GET['jsonp']. '('. $json . ')';
```

How can I take all rows with the same name and combine them so that the spend values will be added up for the same rows, i.e. the two "Gistrup MSN Standard" will be combined and the SPEND value will then be 26 ( 11+15 ).

My JSON output will then contain something like this:

```
NAME                     SPEND    
Gistrup   MSN Standard - 26
Storvorde MSN Standard - 28
Vejgaard  MSN Standard - 30
Aalborg   MSN Standard - 32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your sql by using `group by` clause.
Something like this -

```
SELECT `NAME`, SUM(`SPEND`) FROM <TABLE_NAME> GROUP BY NAME
```

In your case, the query will look something like this -

```
// You will need to add the col names here
$fb_sql = "SELECT `NAME`, SUM(`SPEND`) FROM $table WHERE id_campaign_shortname = '". $_GET["lpage"] ."' AND date_from = '". $date_from ."' AND date_to = '". $date_to ."' GROUP BY NAME";
```

Answer (score 1):

select select id_campaign_shortname, sum(SPEND) group by id_campaign_shortname